# I want to make an image appears when I hover over text. I integrated few JavaScripts but it's still not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show an image but still I can't manage to make it works. Respective parts I need are there like.

```js
function mouseIn() {
  $('.img').addClass('show');
}

function mouseOut() {
  $('.img').removeClass('show');
}

$('.hover-me').hover(mouseIn, mouseOut);
```

```css
.img {
  display: none;
}

.img.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="hover-me">Hi</p>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/150" class="img">
```

Comment: I add similar code at https://codepen.io/bin-umar/pen/XWjPWmm and it works perfectly, thats why add all your code^ in order to see the problem

Comment: @Doom2 as I see, your code is working as you described, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script takes the `.trg` class elements that are in the packaging element `id="wrap"`. When you hold the mouse over some target elements it starts to run time (*I have currently set 500ms*). The time is set to the variable `var delay = 500`. When this time expires, the script takes the `data` attribute of the target element and creates a new element img. When you remove the mouse cursor from the target element, all elements with class `.img` are removed... thus the created image is removed.

For site optimization, this method is better because you will not load content that is invisible... but you will create it when needed.

*With small adjustments to my code, you can change it to add a class to an existing element or work in another way that works for you.*

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var delay = 500; // <-- delay time in ms
    var wrp = '#wrap';
    var mouseMove;
    var url;
    var el;
    var show = true;

    $(wrp + ' .trg').on('mouseenter', function () {
        mouseMove = new Date().getTime();
        show = true;
        el = this;
        url = $(this).attr('data');
    });

    $(wrp + ' .trg').on('mouseout', function () {
        $('.img').remove();
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        var curTime = new Date().getTime();
        if (curTime - mouseMove > delay && $(wrp + ':hover').length != 0 && show) {
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.setAttribute('class', 'img');
            img.setAttribute('src', url);
            el.append(img);
            show = false;
        }
    }, delay);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrap">
    <div class="trg" data="https://blog.54ka.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/horses-on-summer-meadow_027_by_54ka-165x165.jpg">Lorem 01</div>
    <div class="trg" data="https://blog.54ka.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/horses-on-summer-meadow_005_by_54ka-165x165.jpg">Lorem 02</div>
    <div class="trg" data="https://blog.54ka.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/horses-on-summer-meadow_006_by_54ka-165x165.jpg">Lorem 03</div>
</div>
```

**Example 2**

This example is based on your code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var delay = 500; // <-- delay time in ms
    var wrp = '.hover-me';
    var mouseMove;
    var show = true;

    $(wrp).on('mouseenter', function () {
        mouseMove = new Date().getTime();
        show = true;
    });

    $(wrp).on('mouseout', function () {
        $('.img').removeClass('show');
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        var curTime = new Date().getTime();
        if (curTime - mouseMove > delay && $(wrp + ':hover').length != 0 && show) {
            $('.img').addClass('show');
            show = false;
        }
    }, delay);

});
```

```css
.img {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="hover-me">Hi</p>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/150" class="img">
```